# iOS Advanced - Make a sound in background with iOS and app closed without notifications

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, notifications

The other day I bought a Tile Slim (Bluetooth Tracker) to be able to locate my wallet. What I didn't know is that I could also locate my phone with a button that the Tile had. As a developer I thought that the only way to do that, would be having the app opened, but my surprise was that even if I close the Tile App, it still worked.

This is happening with iPhone (iOS) I don't care about Android.

How is it possible that with the iPhone locked and the Tile App closed it's able to increase the volume to a 100% and make a sound that stops only when I press any volume side button (and even with notifications disabled)?

Here is a video showing it in real life:
https://vimeo.com/679108480/6ac7919287

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What if you turn off Bluetooth on the phone?

Comment: Then doesn't work, the signal comes by bluetooth by the tracker but I don't think that it comes because of that.

Comment: It’s probably using a combination of Bluetooth together with local notifications which I don’t think needs remote push notifications enabled, but wait the app is completely exited? I thought maybe it’s running a background process and also has background audio capabilities activated … interesting

Comment: I see what you're saying: you think bluetooth is used to know that the phone is nearby but is not the actual form of communication? I'm not so sure. Also please note that your local notification setting is irrelevant. That setting prevents notification info from being _displayed_ — it has nothing to do with whether a notification is _received_. So it could still be a push notification. What I would do now is put the device into Airplane mode but then turn Bluetooth on. If the signal works, it's just Bluetooth. If not, it's a push notification.

Comment: Hi cohen72 yeah it's exited and still works, so curious. Ok @matt, I didn't know that. I don't understand why setting it on airplane mode would lock the push notifications to run, but I tried it and still working if bluetooth is on and everything else is disabled. So who knows how this actually works!

Comment: If it's on airplane mode, there is no network. So if this were a signal coming via a push notification, it wouldn't be able to arrive. Therefore, as I originally proposed, it is using nearby-bluetooth. I really don't see why you rejected that idea up front. When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbably, must be the truth.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I assume that the bluetooth is the one who sends the signal to the phone, but I don't understand what can it activate that allows to modify the volume and play a sound fully in background with the app closed. And then assuming that's possible, I wonder if there's any way to be able to do the same but programmed from an app (like an alarm), without the bluetooth signal.

Comment: Maybe the Tile broadcasts a Beacon over BlueTooth. Apps can register to listen for them, and iOS will wake an app up if one is detected. I was experimenting with this years ago. Once awake the app has time to actually have additional transaction over Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

An app that supports background audio can play audio even if the ring/silent switch is set to silent.

There is a summary table [in this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH10)

The Tile app will have background audio and background Bluetooth support.

The will have code something like:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    // Get the singleton instance.
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        // Set the audio session category, mode, and options.
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [defaultToSpeaker])
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set audio session category.")
    }
    
    // Other post-launch configuration.
    return true
}
```

The app would also be waiting for connections and notifications from the Tile peripheral using Bluetooth background mode with state restoration.

When the app gets the Bluetooth event it will [activate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616597-setactive) its audio session and begin playback.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I know that background audio allows you even if it's in silent, but even if the app is closed, do you think it still can run the audio? Then my other concern would be if I can play an audio at a specific time in silent even if the app is closed (without bluetooth trigger).

Comment: You can't play audio if the app is closed. Bluetooth state restoration means the Tile app is no longer closed. It has been relaunched in the background to handle the Bluetooth event.